# Accessing a PDO instance from another class

Tags: php, class, pdo

Here is my db class for connecting with database using pdo ext.

```
class db
{
    private $host;
    private $dbname;
    private $username;
    private $password;

    public function __construct($host,$db,$name,$pass)
    {
         $this->host=$host;
         $this->dbname=$db;
         $this->username=$name;
         $this->password=$pass;
         $dsn = 'mysql:'.$this->dbname.';'.$this->host;
         try 
         {
            $conn = new PDO($dsn, $this->username, $this->password);


            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         } 
         catch(PDOException $e) 
         {
              echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
         }
 }
}
```

I call db class in login class like this...

```
$host='localhost';
        $db='techy_issue_tracker';
        $name='root';
        $pass='';
        $base= new db($host,$db,$name,$pass);
```

Here is the problem, to make a pdo query inside login class (extending db class) if I use a line this...

```
$stmnt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE name :name OR email = :email');
```

It generates two errors, saying.. 
**Notice: Undefined variable: conn... and 
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object...**

I can fix this by simply putting all pdo stuff inside login class but still I am just curious...how do you guys call an object (which is an instance of pdo class?) from another class.

[PHP Class Based User System With PDO - Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368129/php-class-based-user-system-with-pdo-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a) This question is interesting but didn't understand much :/

Didn't practice OOP much so some good explanation would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to intialize `$conn` as a public property of your `db` class.

After the private properties in your `db` class, add this:

```
public $conn;
```

Then, inside your try catch, change `$conn` to `$this->conn`:

```
$this->conn = new PDO($dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
$this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then, assuming you've correctly extended the `db` class, you can access `conn` in this manner:

`$stmt = $db->conn->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE name :name OR email = :email');`

Comment: Elliot B is right you are constructing your class but then trying to reference something that has not been defined. The above method would solve your problem.

Comment: I've tried that before...didn't work :/ Still I'm getting **Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object** error.

Check if I've extended in right way..
`class signup extends db
    {
     $stmnt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE name :name OR email = :email');
}`

Comment: You should post your full code with the method I've described. There's something else you're not doing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a method to the db class that takes in a sql string and returns an array of object. Just do all the statement thingy in that method. Then the login class can just call this method to do any query. It does not need to know how the database connection is implemented. This way, if you want to change the underlying implementation in future. It only affects the db class. Not much changes is to be done to the login class as all database accesses goes through the db class.

Comment: Interesting...but how is that possible with a single method? query template is not same always (so I gotta pass different set of params)...so I have to create unique method whenever template is different then call them from any class that extends db. Am I right?

Comment: For my project, the method takes in an array of criteria that maps to each field in the where part of the sql. It then escapes and generate the sql statement and executes it.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE name :name
```

You're missing an equal sign:

```
WHERE name = :name
```